# set language for google maps iframe

Tags: google-maps

I have changed the language for the google maps to Hebrew in the language setting but I would like to use the `<iframe>` code for my website. However, I can only seem to get this in English. How do I set it for Hebrew? 
The URL has hl=he but I can't seem to get it to work for the `<iframe>` code. 
My code is:

`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d27130.99130966173!2d35.186535!3d31.787558!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1502d64c6e5bf91d%3A0x2f55a98e4e4ab5e9!2z15vXoNek15kg16DXqdeo15nXnSAxNQ!5e0!3m2!1siw!2s!4v1395222081666" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>`

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to add `language` parameter of API call for embed map. For Hebrew language, `src` of `<iframe>` should be like:

```
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d27130.99130966173!2d35.186535!3d31.787558!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1502d64c6e5bf91d%3A0x2f55a98e4e4ab5e9!2z15vXoNek15kg16DXqdeo15nXnSAxNQ!5e0!3m2!1siw!2s!4v1395222081666&language=iw"
```

- More info at [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)
- More info about Google Maps API language support:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport

Comment: @KevinCittadini looks like that document doesn't exist anymore, I'll remove that link and search for another resource whenever I'm available.

Comment: In FAQ section of Google Maps API, the supported languages are listed, the link is added to the answer.

Comment: My embedded map was in arabic so I used this command : hl=en.
It is working perfectly.

Comment: Does not work, but it works when you go to google.<your country>/maps => share => embed map => copy link to your website.

Comment: @Muflix unfortunately that doesn't work for my use case. I have a ready made iframe snippet that I must embed, "but the language must be adaptive" customer says, but it seems the language is encoded somehow in the `pb` parameter and takes precedence :/

Answer (score 17):

idk if this is really functional for other countrys but when im building a mock, and i found a google map iframe, and my client is by Example: US but im Mx the:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3063.7150513838938!2d-84.19918628432937!3d39.83580597943695!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x884081e28cd77f07%3A0xf7f318d105021243!2sBuckeye+Harley-Davidson!5e0!3m2!**1ses!2smx**!4v1556548028269!5m2!**1ses!2smx**"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

i just update this info in the Url, **1sen!2sus**, then the iframe is shown in english.

i hope this can helps to you to.

Comment: In 2019 this is the one that did it for me. When embedding the iframe change the four occurrences of [this is an example, from English to Spanish] 1sen!2sen to 1ses!2ses

Comment: Works, thank you. Wanted to change the language from German to French:
`1sde` -> `1sfr`

Comment: Holy Cow, it's works very well `2022`.

Comment: Works well for me as well (2023). I had the Slovak `sk_SK` locale and I wanted to change it to Swiss `de_CH`. I needed to change `!1ssk!2ssk` to `!1sde!2sch`, note I had 2 occurrences, not just one.

Answer (score 10):

Also you can use link like this -

```
src="https://maps.google.com.ua/maps?q=Майдан+Незалежності,+Київ&hl=uk&output=embed"
```

`Майдан+Незалежності,+Київ` - map locaton

`uk` - language

Comment: Google Maps Platform rejected your request. Invalid request. Unexpected parameter 'hl'.

Answer (score 8):

In 2016 it doesn't work anymore for embedded code directly taken from maps.

But `&language=ru` would work if you generate your code here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

You'll have to create api key.

Answer (score 8):

While using Google Map embeed iframe you can replace default language parametr on the src , you can look at at my example I point the placement of default language code : For example - az for Azerbaijan language

```
  <iframe class="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3038.7779420053535!2d49.85933131574896!3d40.39161387936813!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x40307d151fdf42df%3A0xb3dd9195f4676922!2z0JzQuNC90LjRgdGC0LXRgNGB0YLQstC-INC-0LHRgNCw0LfQvtCy0LDQvdC40Y8g0JDQt9C10YDQsdCw0LnQtNC20LDQvdGB0LrQvtC5INCg0LXRgdC_0YPQsdC70LjQutC4!5e0!3m2!1sru!2s!4v1574328901852!5m2!1s{you can find this point and replace with your locale language for example 'az' then iframe will translate into your locale language}!2s" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: This worked for me August 2020. having copied the iframe directly from google maps.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.
I am a Dutchman living in Brazil.
I developed a website for a Brazilian firm.
The result the iframe rendered in the web-page was in Dutch.
Then my client tested the site and everything was in Portuguese.
The answer can be found in the native browser settings (Dutch for me), (Portuguese for my client).

Dirk Detmar
Teresina, Piaui
Brazilie

Comment: This doesn't work as of April 2015. I get the map displayed in English no matter what, and that means REALLY no matter what: no matter which language I set in my google preferences, no matter which language I specify using the language parameter in the URL, and no matter what is my browser language preference.

Answer (score 3):

While using Google Map embed iframe changing the default language parameter works for me. See here which parameter to change:

[image: See here which parameter to change]

In the image currently, the Nepalese language is used and if we change the language parament "ne" to "en", all the text in the map will appear in the English language.

Also, you can change the language parameter from the google maps page. In the bottom right corner, click the location icon which shows your location, and change it to the required country you want.

Answer (score 0):

So to sum the answers to this question up, the language key depends on what API you are using:

- **https://www.google.com/maps/embed**

  key : hl

  [list of possible parameters](https://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters) (search page for keyword "hl")
- **https://www.google.com/maps?output=embed**

  key : language

  [list of possible parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport)

Answer (score 0):

Adding language parameter didn't work for me, I changed the language of Google map with clicking on the hamburger menu and then changing the language, with that I copied the HTML iframe tag again, and now the language is set to the selected language.

Answer (score 0):

Find your language code from end of this code section (signed as bold):

pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d27130.99130966173!2d35.186535!3d31.787558!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1502d64c6e5bf91d%3A0x2f55a98e4e4ab5e9!2z15vXoNek15kg16DXqdeo15nXnSAxNQ!5e0!3m2!1s**iw**!2s!4v1395222081666

and add the this code end of the src: !5m2!1s**iw**

Replace iw with the language code you want.

Sample code with php:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d27130.99130966173!2d35.186535!3d31.787558!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1502d64c6e5bf91d%3A0x2f55a98e4e4ab5e9!2z15vXoNek15kg16DXqdeo15nXnSAxNQ!5e0!3m2!1s<?=$lng?>!2s!4v1395222081666!5m2!1s<?=$lng?>!2str" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```