# Google maps API doesn't change language

Tags: html, google-maps

This is my part of code:

```
<div class="contact-map fullwidth">
<iframe id="contacts-map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2934.840706379279!2d23.333396514681272!3d42.643536825146064!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x40aa84104363e1bf%3A0x52c1ac43c6be263a!2z0YPQuy4g4oCe0J_RitGB0YLRitGAINGB0LLRj9GC4oCcIDExLCAxNzAwINC60LIuINCS0LjRgtC-0YjQsCwg0KHQvtGE0LjRjw!5e0!3m2!1sbg!2sbg!4v1502701860622&language=bg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I tried with `language=bg`, but nothing happend, still english. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google prioritizes browser's language, you can't force it

> EDIT : According to user2513484's comment, it's finally possible changing `src` parameter value. Let's see : [set language for google maps iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503945/set-language-for-google-maps-iframe)

Comment: But take a look here "http://www.bodusod.bg/bg/namerete-ni" My browser is in english, but google map is "en" and "bg"?

Comment: I'm not sure this was true in 2017 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503945/set-language-for-google-maps-iframe but in 2019 you can surely change it in the iframe url where it says [for instance, in the OP example] 1sbg!2sbg, try 1sit!2sit for Italian or 1sen!2sus for US English. (Sometimes it is present twice in the url.)