# Change Google Map iframe language

Tags: google-maps

I have this map with an iframe on my site:

> http://ecotourism.afrika-praktikum.de/zanzibarwebsite/in-kenya/elewana-elephant-pepper-camp-with-game-package/

The controls on the map appear on Spanish (for example: "ampliar mapa")

How can I change the language?

Please no API, I just want to use the iframe.

Answer (score 5):

There is a list of languages in preferable order in the end of an iFrame url:
for example, "!1sru!2sen" would mean use russian language, or english language.

Answer (score 1):

U can use the **language** parameter. Add this to your URL in frame:

```
&language=es
```

And u can check here all the [language codes](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport).
Or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53776703) for alternative to language parameter.

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d7977.847833251129!2d35.14458!3d-1.21321!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x73cb9086bfd8b87c!2sElephant+Pepper+Camp!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sjp!4v1557202274665!5m2!1ses!2sjp&language=en" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

It didn't work.

Comment: @DrawsRenGundam use hl=en if language don't work, is because you don't use api key.

Comment: Where do i put the API key on the frame?

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide, the paramater is **key**

Answer (score 1):

The language parameter is also hashed in the iframe URL. Before you get the HTML code for sharing, access Google maps with the language parameter you need (stated below) and share afterwards. The hl parameter is for the language.

> https://www.google.com/maps?hl=en

Comment: This worked for me for a user-generated map (`https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?hl=en&...`), whereas `?language=en` did not.